# Connect from local SSMS Express to remote server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using my local pc and I installed SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008. I tried to connect database which is on my office server. SO how to connect to server database?

- server computer name : office-d1
- server full computer name:
  office-d1.sge.com

I wrote server name(office-d1\SQLExpress) in server name block in sql server management studio in my local pc.

Comment: and, are you sure that you can *see* that office server from where you are?

Comment: yes, I am on the same network and I can remotely access my server

Comment: what kind of authentication do your office server needs?, windows?, user and password?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear to me. Do you mean to find the server name?

The server name could be filled using:

-The exact name as you type

-The IP address (ask the admin to know this)

-Click on the dropdown menu -> browse for more -> network.. and search if you are directly connected.

Make sure your office SQL server is configured to open for you. Check your firewall if there is any.

Comment: When I click on drop down menu . I found my server name. I selected but still i got error "can not connect to office-d1"

Comment: additional information: login failed for user  'emp1'( error:18456)

Comment: Check your firewall (inbound) and your office firewall (outbound) as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Local server name : COMP110
>
> Network server name : NHI-DR1
>
> ```
> When I search for network sql server and try to connect to network sql server, it displays error.
>
> TITLE: Connect to Server
> ------------------------------
>
> Cannot connect to NHI-DR1.
>
> ------------------------------
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user 'NHD\COMP110'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------
> BUTTONS:
>
> OK
> ------------------------------
> ```
>
> But when I tried to connect my local server COMP110 from network
> server (NHI-DR1) then it works good. I can access all database from
> local server.